# Generate a calendar without holidays and weekends

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to generate a calendar  with the number of hours worked by an agent without weekends and holidays.
My first svtep: I started with a simple calendar using  my source table, this is an  example of how rows looks like:

ID :15
StartDate:2022-01-24 00:00:00.0000000
StartPeriod:AM
EndDate :2022-01-2800:00:00.0000000
EndPeriod:PM
Duration :35
DurationType :heure

I could generate some new rows using this PS:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_repos_absence]  AS

SET DATEFIRST 1 

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = (SELECT CAST(MIN(StartDate) as date) FROM SOURCE)
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = (SELECT CAST(MAX(EndDate) as date ) FROM SOURCE)

TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[RCAbsenceDay]

;WITH GeneratedDates AS
(
    SELECT
        GeneratedDate = @StartDate

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        GeneratedDate = DATEADD(hour,12,G.GeneratedDate)
    FROM
        GeneratedDates AS G
        
    WHERE  G.GeneratedDate < @EndDate  
     -- WHERE (G.GeneratedDate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)

),SpecialDays AS
(
    SELECT
        Date = G.GeneratedDate,
        Year = YEAR(G.GeneratedDate),
        Month = MONTH(G.GeneratedDate),
        Day = DAY(G.GeneratedDate),
        IsWeekend = CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, G.GeneratedDate) IN (6, 7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        IsHoliday = CASE WHEN H.[Date] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM
        GeneratedDates AS G
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[PublicHoliday] H ON G.GeneratedDate = H.[Date] AND H.Area = 'Métropole'
)
, Calendar as 
(
SELECT
    Date = S.Date,
    Year = S.Year,
    Month = S.Month,
    Day = S.Day,
    IsWeekend = S.IsWeekend,
    IsHoliday = S.IsHoliday,
    --BusinessHoursStartTime = CASE WHEN S.IsHoliday = 0 AND S.IsWeekend = 0 THEN CONVERT(TIME, '08:00:00') END,
    --BusinessHoursEndTIme   = CASE WHEN S.IsHoliday = 0 AND S.IsWeekend = 0 THEN CONVERT(TIME, '17:00:00') END,
    IsWork = CASE   WHEN S.IsWeekend + S.IsHoliday >= 1   THEN 0 ELSE 1 END

FROM
    SpecialDays AS S
    --  order by 1 asc
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[AbsenceDay]
Select      
         C.Date AS StartDate
        ,C.Date AS EndDate
        ,CASE 
            WHEN A.StartDate <> C.Date 
            THEN 'AM'
            ELSE A.StartPeriod
         END AS StartPeriod
         ,CASE
            WHEN A.EndDate <> C.Date
            THEN 'PM'
            ELSE A.EndPeriod
         END AS EndPeriod
        ,CASE WHEN A.StartPeriod='AM'and  A.EndPeriod='AM'
              THEN 4    
            ELSE 3.55
         END AS Duration
        ,A.ID AS [ID_absence]
from [dbo].[SOURCE] A

inner join Calendar C ON C.Date BETWEEN A.StartDate AND A.EndDate AND IsWork = 1
option (maxrecursion 10000)
```

the result :  I get something like this :  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCXhG.png)

My first question: how can I get the last row of 28/01?

My second question: an agent work from 08h00 to 12:00 and from 13:300 to 17:00 there is a way two split my calendar in this way instead of 00 and 12 like in the second picture?

Comment: For the first question, since you appear to be working in 12 hour increments, do you need to `CAST(MAX(EndDate) as datetime )` instead of `as date` or otherwise add 12 hours to @EndDate?  As for the second question, I think we need a lot more information on how your shifts work and how single vs split shifts are represented in your source table, sample data and expected results. Please provide a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: thank you for your answer, when I remove  max date (the DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = (SELECT EndDate  FROM SOURCE)) i get this error Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.usp_repos_compensatoire, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 93]
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.